# How to find a depth of a directory

Tags: command-line, find, directory, directory-structure

Is there a way to find a maximum depth of given directory tree? I was thinking about using find with incrementing maxdepth and comparing number of found directories, but maybe there is a simpler way?

Comment: Is depth how many folders down from the `/` folder you are?

Comment: no, it is depth under the current folder

Comment: So are you trying to work out how many folders are under the, for example, `/home` directory?

Comment: here you go : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329369/recursive-function-to-return-directory-depth-of-file-tree/9743955#9743955 (Recursive Function to Return Directory Depth of File Tree

)

Answer (score 17):

One way to do it, assuming GNU `find`:

```
find . -type d -printf '%d\n' | sort -rn | head -1
```

This is not particularly efficient, but it's certainly much better than trying different `-maxdepth`s in turn.

Answer (score 7):

Try this, for example trying to find max depth of tree under `/`, using

```
find / -type d
```

will give every directory under `/` irrespective of depth. So `awk` the result with `/` as delimiter to find the count, and `count-1`  would give max depth of tree from `/`, so the command would be:

```
find / -type d | awk -F"/" 'NF > max {max = NF} END {print max}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `updatedb` and then `locate`. It performs really fast, as `locate` queries a database and it's much faster than asking for each file sepereately. `updatedb` is fast too, since it only updates the database with changes instead of creating it anew. The only drawback is that you may need root privilages to run `updatedb` by default, unless you make and preserve your own, user-space database.

Keep in mind that you may have newlines in your filenames, so that you need to be more careful about processing `locate`'s output. Best to use null byte as a filename separator.

To sum it up:

`updatedb && locate -0 "$(pwd)" | awk -v RS='\0' -F"/" '{print NF-1}' | sort -n | tail -n1`

Thanks @sai sasanka for providing me with a perfect awk script.

Comment: `updatedb` runs `find`, so this can't be faster than running `find` just to extract the desired information.

Comment: @Gilles [it does not run `find`.](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/mlocate.git/tree/src/updatedb.c?h=master&id=9054d66c61878fe79f7da568c0e4af37f60086ff)
From `man updatedb` "If the database already exists, its data is **reused** to avoid rereading directories that have not changed.".  We are counting on reusing the database. Moreover, it can be seen as preprocessing which allows you to answer quickly for many queries. On my system with HDD drive `updatedb` took 2 seconds to finish, so it's really fast compared to other solutions.

Comment: Using updatedb would be useful to make *multiple* queries, which is not mentioned in the question. Even so, `updatedb` records all files, which is a waste: for this, only directories are useful, so running and storing the output of `find -type d` would be faster.

Comment: @Gilles from `man updatedb` "`updatedb` is usually run daily by `cron`(8) to update the default database.". Unless the OP has created and deleted many files in his filesystem it's much faster to update it and query the database than to run it again. And based on [ext4 filesystem documentation](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Directory_Entries) it doesn't really matter if you apply `-d` flag or not. You must read the whole directory table anyway to check `filetype` flag of each file - and when reading this flag OS will load sequential bytes (with filename) to memory.

Comment: Unless *no* directory has been created, moved or deleted since the last `updatedb` run, it's necessary to run `updatedb` again. It *is* possible to optimize `find -type d` to not read the whole directory table, and in particular to not read the content of a leaf directory: the hard link count on a directory indicates how many subdirectories it has. GNU find does not implement this optimization though.

Comment: It's necessary to rerun `updatedb` only if you have altered the structure you are now querying about. Anyway, `updatedb` tracks changes and may return much faster than `find`. My solution is a suggestion to consider, not a general rule which has to be applied every time. One must know pros and cons of solutions and apply which suits best.